# Datagrid Edit cell when got focus

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid ,with four columns say Item Name,Purchase Rate,Qty,Amount .Where I want to set the Qty cell editable and also select cell content when it got focus,Also I want to focus to the cell say Amount Cell when Press Enter key from the Qty column how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
//Focus to cell
dataGrid1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid1.Items[/*index*/], dataGrid1.Columns[/*index*/]);
//Begins edit
dataGrid1.BeginEdit();
```